# Владивосток, Владикавказ — этимология и словообразование

Tags: этимология, словообразование, топонимика, сложные-слова

Почему соединительной гласной в словах Владивосток и Владикавказ является буква "и", а не "е"?

Answer (score 1):

По историческим справкам, название было дано городу конкретным человеком (генерал-аншефом Потёмкиным), со значением "**владей Кавказом**". Никто не руководствовался теоретической идеей "правильной" соединительной гласной (это, скорее, привело бы к какому-нибудь "кавказовладению" - с другим порядком следования корней). Тем не менее, название в таком виде прижилось не по "волюнтаристским" причинам. Можно усмотреть в нём сокращение созвучного исходной идее ("владей Кавказом") словосочетания "Влад**ы**ка Кавказа" - здесь переход через "**и**" воспринимается вполне естественно. Владивосток был назван по простой аналогии с Владикавказом.

Answer (score 1):

Цитата из Википедии: "В русском языке, согласно принципам народной этимологии, вторая часть имени Влади(мир) была переосмыслена под влиянием существительных миръ («спокойствие»), міръ («вселенная»), «мѣра» (мера, размеренность, упорядоченность), а всё имя, таким образом, стали понимать как означающее «владеющий миром»."

Можно предположить, что названия Владивосток и Владикавказ произведены от топонима Владимир путем замены составляющей "мир" на "восток" и "Кавказ" соответственно.